# select distinct does not list first entry, select does, why?

Tags: mysql

I have a strange issue with select distinct, when i use the following code:

```
SELECT 

T2.cited_pat_publn_id,
T2.cited_publn_auth,
T2.cited_publn_nr,
T2.cited_publn_kind,
T2.cited_appln_id,
T2.cited_publn_date,
T3.citing_pat_publn_id,
T3.citing_publn_auth,
T3.citing_publn_nr,
T3.citing_publn_kind,
T3.citing_appln_id,
T3.citing_publn_date

FROM (tls211_pat_publn T0, albert_my_ipc T1, albert_my_cited T2, albert_my_citing T3) 

WHERE  
T1.appln_id=T0.appln_id 
AND 
T2.cited_pat_publn_id=T0.pat_publn_id 
AND 
T3.citing_pat_publn_id=T2.citing_pat_publn_id
AND
TRIM(T0.publn_nr)="6174338"


limit 1,5000
```

i get all citing_pat_publn_ids i wanted...

but when i use select distinct the first id is not listed...

thank you for any suggestion!

Result with only select(only posted here the first 4 rows..):

```
cited_pat_publn_id  cited_publn_auth    cited_publn_nr  cited_publn_kind        cited_appln_id  cited_publn_date    citing_pat_publn_id citing_publn_auth   citing_publn_nr citing_publn_kind   citing_appln_id citing_publn_date

62554677    US  6174338 B1  48980223    16.01.2001  59255528    US  8048557 B2  45960521    01.11.2011
62554677    US  6174338 B1  48980223    16.01.2001  59255528    US  8048557 B2  45960521    01.11.2011
62554677    US  6174338 B1  48980223    16.01.2001  59255528    US  8048557 B2  45960521    01.11.2011
62554677    US  6174338 B1  48980223    16.01.2001  59255528    US  8048557 B2  45960521    01.11.2011
```

result with select distinct (only posted here the first 2rows, there are more):

```
cited_pat_publn_id  cited_publn_auth    cited_publn_nr  cited_publn_kind    cited_appln_id  cited_publn_date    citing_pat_publn_id citing_publn_auth   citing_publn_nr citing_publn_kind   citing_appln_id citing_publn_date
62554677    US  6174338 B1  48980223    16.01.2001  61120611    US  6844106 B2  47693584    18.01.2005
62554677    US  6174338 B1  48980223    16.01.2001  65427309    US  6517975 B1  51553339    11.02.2003
```

there is no citing_pat_publn_id=45960521

Comment: could you provide at least your fist row returned in the result set for both attempts? or better include your desired output as a whole.

Comment: how can you define the first ID? you are using LIMIT but you are not using an ORDER BY

Comment: Oh, thank you! that could it be :) I try it and let you know.

Comment: Also, TRIM your data when you store it. The function negates the possibility of an index, which is *really* inefficient. And please, please use explicit JOIN syntax. It will make your queries much easier to read.

Comment: Hi, I tried and used                                               GROUP BY T3.citing_pat_publn_id
ORDER BY T3.citing_pat_publn_id
DESC but the results show only 4 out of 5 results